# VSCODE does not work for me on Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Just learned about VSCODE, excited to try it. I downloaded, unzipped and ran the executable. I get:

```
$ Code
[2183:0429/201254:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
bash: .bashrc: No such file or directory
^C
```

At that point no window appears, nothing happens, and all I can do it ^C out of it. I can't see anything in the instructions that I'm supposed to do besides run it. Anyone else have this problem?

[Arch Linux 4.0.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Arch Linux a package is available in the AUR. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code/.

This AUR package has

```
alsa-lib
cairo
fontconfig
gcc-libs
gconf
gtk2
libxtst
nss
python
```

as its dependencies. The installation of those dependencies from your package manager should fix the problem. I tried to replicate the error by removing the packages but i had no success.

I get the first part of the error message as well. It seems it can be ignored since the editor starts as expected.

```
[7190:0501/233446:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
```

Comment: What's the solution to the problem? Could you please explain what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Same happening at me.
At the Visual Studio Code official FAQ they state, they are aware of the issue. They don't have solution yet: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/FAQ
I would keep checking that page, over time they'll most likely upload the solution there.

Comment: My initial interest in VSC was based on a misunderstanding. I am very much interested in doing debugging with it, but have no interest in using it as an editor.  Apparently it is only an editor for now.

Answer (score 0):

The project maybe have many watchers.
I run this and fix that problem:

```
# increasing the capacity of watchers

echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```