# Running VS Code on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded VSCode-linux-x64.zip. When I try to extract it using GUI it fails:

[image: Extract archive error]

The archive can be extracted using terminal and no resulting errors:

```
$ unzip VSCode-linux-x64.zip
```

If I then try to open the program Code from terminal I get the following results:

```
$ ./Code 
[21746:0430/141853:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
[21746:0430/141854:WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(30)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: 0/1
[atom event]: render process crashed!
```

I can either quit using Ctrl+C here or let Code pop up to tell me:

[image: VS Code crashes during start up]

This error also occurs if I try to open Code by double clicking the icon.

[VSCODE does not work for me on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958452/vscode-does-not-work-for-me-on-linux) has the same problem, but since I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and not Arch Linux, I suppose their solution doesn't apply to me.

Comment: My Code runs just fine. When starting, I get the same messages in my terminal, so I guess they are normal.

On the official site, they state that this program is still preview. There is probably not much you can do but waiting for the release.

Comment: @Janman the team also wrote that we could use SO to 'engage' (whatever they mean by that). Since they aren't responding on Twitter, I went here. I guess I'll wait until the preview is a bit more mature.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, just unzip from the command line

```
unzip VSCode-linux-x64.zip
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I was able to extract using command line. It still doesn't solve the problem of running Code.

Comment: This is weird. I am getting the same error. I don't understand how extracting it a different way will cause the error to disappear. What else did you do differently?

Comment: Something else is at play here. I tried extracting on the command line and it made no difference. Can you please try to extract using the UI and verify that you get the same error? _I think_ you may have done a system update that fixed the error, so extracting using the UI then loading it will cause it to work correctly. Thanks!